# Django test stuck on migrations/permissions

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

So, I noticed that my tests were not running and seem stuck so I ran them locally with `--verbosity 3` optional argument.

The log seems stuck after my last application permission creation.

```
Running post-migrate handlers for application vehicles
...
Adding permission 'Permission object (78)'
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

The last part seems rather confusing - I am not calling django.setup() or run server anywhere in the code.

Relevant pieces of info. I use a proxy model in `authentication.models` and I updated the settings accordingly. `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.User'` and I have two strings for heroku `db_from_env=dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)` and `DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)`

This is only unorthodox settings.

Where would I be able to locate how this issue happens and how to tackle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this:

The system check was added in Django 1.8 and I never paid attention - do not look in that direction.

The database is fine as well.

What seemed to be an issue for me was that I had `signals` being blocked by a wrong method, thus resulting in a hanging connection to an external services (in my case Algolia).

Another part of the issue was that if I was using fixtures in `APITestCase` I have had to use `setUpClass(cls)` to disconnect the signals.

Now the issue is not completely gone, but at least I know that `python manage.py test --reverse` works.